# Android - Get Started with Vulkan - Project files mentioned in tutorial are not generated

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I'm following this tutorial from Google on getting started with Vulkan.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started

On Step 4, I generate the Android sample project, which apparently works fine according to the output in the terminal.

[image: Step 4]

```
$ ./bldsys/scripts/generate_android_gradle.sh
-- Android Gradle Project (With Native Support) generated at:
    /Users/elliptic1/workspace/Vulkan-Samples/build/android_gradle
```

On Step 5, I'm able to open the project and find the exact file mentioned

`Vulkan-Samples/build/android_gradle/build.gradle`

But I get lost when it says `You should see something similar to the following`

[image]

I do not see that, instead, I see

[image]

And looking in the directories via the terminal, I can see that those files and dirs are not there.
`manifests`, `java`, `cpp` are not there. Do I have any `cpp` directories, for example? I have these:

```
$ find . -name cpp                                
./third_party/spirv-cross/samples/cpp
./third_party/imgui/misc/cpp
```

So my question is, have I don't something wrong somewhere, or is this tutorial out of date? Is there an updated version somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem, I think,

For me, the Gradle build thinks the NDK is not installed.

The local.properties file that was generated for me has an entry to point at the Android SDK.

This is the main part of my `build/android_gradle/local.properties` file:

```
#Mon Jun 13 15:11:38 EDT 2022
sdk.dir=/Users/dneto/Library/Android/sdk
```

When I modify it to also set ndk.dir, my build works:

```
#Mon Jun 13 15:11:38 EDT 2022
sdk.dir=/Users/dneto/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/dneto/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888
```

I don't know why this extra step is needed.  It seems like a bug somewhere along the line.